# How can I use a while loop in this code?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, do-while

I am working through Learn Java The Hard Way and I am stuck on this study drill, which is to use a while loop to do the same thing as this code. I was wondering if you guys could help me out. Most of my attempts have resulted in an infinite while loop, which is what I do not want.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class RunningTotal
{   
    public static void main( String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int current, total = 0;

        System.out.print("Type in a bunch of values and I'll ad them up. ");
        System.out.println( "I'll stop when you type a zero." );

        do
        {   
            System.out.print(" Value: ");
            current = input.nextInt();
            int newtotal = current + total;
            total = newtotal; 
            System.out.println("The total so far is: " + total);
        }while (current != 0);

        System.out.println( "Final total: " + total);

    }
}
```

Comment: Use a flag variable, make it `true` before the `while` loop, and make that your `while` condition. When it comes time to get out of the loop, set the flag to `false`. Or, use `true` for your `while` condition, check for `current` to become zero, and then break out of the loop using a `break` statement.

Comment: Do one iteration outside the loop.

Answer (score 3):

A solution that doesn't change all that much code:

```
int current = -1;

while (current != 0) {
    System.out.print(" Value: ");
    current = input.nextInt();
    int newtotal = current + total;
    total = newtotal; 
    System.out.println("The total so far is: " + total);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why are you processing(adding to total) when user has entered 0. I know it makes no difference but why unnecessary computations?

Also why define `int newtotal` in each loop. You can simply add the sum to the total.

So the while loop code will go something as follows

```
    while((current = input.nextInt()) != 0) {
       total = total + current;
        System.out.println("The total so far is: " + total);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

*Turning my comment into an answer:*

One possible solution:

```
boolean flag = true;
while(flag)
{   
    System.out.print(" Value: ");
    current = input.nextInt();
    int newtotal = current + total;
    total = newtotal; 
    System.out.println("The total so far is: " + total);
    if(current == 0)
        flag = false;
}
```

Another possible solution:

```
while(true)
{
    System.out.print(" Value: ");
    current = input.nextInt();
    int newtotal = current + total;
    total = newtotal; 
    System.out.println("The total so far is: " + total);
    if(current == 0)
        break;
}
```

Comment: (I'm not the downvoter by the way) Yes, but your solution adds an extra level that's only going to confuse someone who's just starting to learn.

Comment: @DennisMeng I'm sorry, what do you mean by "extra level"?

Comment: In the original example, you could just look at the loop condition, and be able to infer about what the code does (we're looping until said condition is false). However, by using the flags and a `while (true)`, you've taken that away. Now you have to hunt through to find where the exiting condition is.

Answer (score -1):

What about the next:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Type in a bunch of values and I'll ad them up. ");
System.out.println( "I'll stop when you type a zero." );

int total = 0;
for (int current = -1; current != 0;) {
    System.out.print(" Value: ");
    current = input.nextInt();
    total += current; 
    System.out.println("The total so far is: " + total);
}

System.out.println( "Final total: " + total);
```

Comment: OP has asked for while loop why provide a for loop?